# Noindex when product list has only few products shown

Tags: magento-1, product-list, seo, meta

*Hello,*

I'm currently searching how to **noindex** a product list page **when there is** for example, **less than 3 products shown**, in order to improve SEO.

Could you please give me any advice to realize it ?

*Thank you for your assistance, have a nice day.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to observer the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`

```
<events>
    <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
        <observers>
            <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
                <class>Namespace_Company_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>setRobotsTag</method>
            </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
</event>
```

and set the robots tag like this:

```
public function setRobotsTag($observer) 
{
     $controller = $observer->getAction();
     $action = $controller->getFullActionName();
     if ($action == 'catalog_category_view') {
          $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
          if ($category && $category->getProductCount() < 3) {
              $observer->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setRobots('NOINDEX,FOLLOW');
          }
     }
}
```